# How to replace a razor only outlet with a gfci

Tags: bathroom, gfci

So when I opened the razor only outlet, I found 2 wires connected to either a pair of white and black wires. I'm not sure how to determine which white goes with which black. Help?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect to two black wires that go to the back of the outlet and add a white wire and a black where there instead, matching the colors of the existing wires. Connect these new wires to the back of the GFCI at the line terminals.

to make this work you're probably going to need a new cover on that electrical box too, some sort of flat mud ring.

Get some white glue and dilute it 50% with water and use that to stick the torn paper back down.